# Dragula hide list bullets while dragging

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop, dragula

I am trying to create a sortable list of images using [Dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula).

In this list i dont want the bullets to be visible. The problem I am experiencing is that as I drag an element, the bullet for that element returns.

I have tried using the standard way to hide the bullets in css

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

this works as long as an item is not being dragged around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the marker list items by setting an empty string as the ::marker pseudo-element content.
In your case

```css
ul li::marker {
    content: "";
}
```